# General solution for a cascading recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, summation, recurrence-relations, combinations

**My main question:**

Starting from a simple recurrence relation:

\begin{equation}
Y_i = aY_{i-1}+(1-a)X_i\tag{1}
\end{equation}

I can easily find that the general solution, if $Y_0=0$, is:

\begin{equation}
Y_n = (1-a)\sum_{i=1}^n (a^{i-1}) X_{n-i+1} \tag{2}
\end{equation}

If I consider a second recurrence relation:

\begin{equation}
Z_i = bZ_{i-1} + (1-b)Y_i\tag{3}
\end{equation}

then some work, and the assumption $Z_0=0$ shows the general solution to be:

\begin{equation}
Z_n = \frac{(1-a)(1-b)}{a-b}\sum_{i=1}^n (a^i-b^i) X_{n-i+1} \tag{4}
\end{equation}

**can this be generalised for further repeated recurrences?**

*My progress / observations thus far:*

I noted that, I could write (2) in a different way to make it look a bit more like (4):

\begin{equation}
Y_n = \frac{(1-a)}{a}\sum_{i=1}^n (a^{i}) X_{n-i+1}
\end{equation}

but I am sure that this does not hold if I add a further recurrence.  However, I noted that the coefficients generated by (2) and (4) follow a similar pattern.  For example, for $n=4$ they are:

\begin{align}
(1-a)X_4 & \quad & (1-a)(1-b)X_4\\
(1-a)aX_3 & \quad & (1-a)(1-b)(a+b)X_3\\
(1-a)a^2X_2 & \quad & (1-a)(1-b)(a^2 + ab +b^2)X_2\\
(1-a)a^3X_1 & \quad & (1-a)(1-b)(a^3 + a^2b + ab^2 +b^3)X_1\\
\end{align}

and so on...

For the third recursion the first few coefficients are:

\begin{align}
(1-c)(1-b)(1-a)X_4&\\
(1-c)(1-b)(1-a)(a+b+c)X_3&\\
(1-c)(1-b)(1-a)(a^2+ab+b^2+ca+cb+c^2)X_2&\\
(1-c)(1-b)(1-a)(a^3+a^2b+a^2c+ac^2+bc^2+b^2c+c^3+ab^2+b^3+abc)X_1&
\end{align}

I can see that there is some particular combinatorial formula being used to generate the final brackets, and I can see the pattern - for $a$ and $b$ it is each unique combination of power $i$ from a and b, and then with $a$, $b$ and $c$ the same - is there a particular relation to generate this pattern automatically?

Comment: +1 To your query, for clear presentation and very nice work shown.  Also, I regard it as an interesting math problem.  Personally, I don't know the answer here; I am out of my depth on your query.

Comment: Interesting question! I corrected what I think was a typo in $(3)$, if I was wrong feel free to re-correct.